# Problem with access values in a drop down

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a problem with my code. So, I have two options from where I can choose a project and a project variant. Also I have drop downs that need to be load with data based on proj and proj variant. It's looking like that:

[image]

[image]

My problem is that after I chose the values for project and variant project, nothings happen in drop down only if I go in other page like Build Warnings and I come back.

To implement this I used a SidebarComponent where I sett the project variant selected

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit { 
  selectProject : Project;
  selectVariantProject: ProjectVariant;
  sel = null;

  getProjectVariantId(id :number):void{
    this.projectService.getProjectVariant(id)
    this.projectService.sel = id;
     console.log('Project variant from SIDEBAR select is:' + 
 }
}
```

I use a TableComponent, where I try to obtain the builds based on proj variant selected.

```
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {
  getBuilds(projectVariantId: number): void{
    this.misraService.getBuilds(projectVariantId)
      .subscribe(builds => {
        this.builds = builds;
    });
}


export class MisraService {
   getBuilds(projectVariantId:any): Observable<any>{
   var url = this.urlGetBuilds;
   url = url + "?projectVariantId="+ projectVariantId ;
   console.log('Variant id build MISRA SERVICE select is:' + projectVariantId)

   return this.http.get<Build>(url)
     .pipe(
     catchError(this.handleError('getMisraMessages',[]))
  );
  }
 }
```

After I run the project it's look like this : 
[image]

If you have an idea what the problem is, let me know. Thanks! :)

Comment: The error in the console is a 500 error, which means some kind of issue with the server you are trying to talk to. How is your server on port 8888 configured?

Comment: Yes, my server is on port 8888.

Comment: I mean you should check the implementation of the server. Something is falling over when it receives the request, hence the 500.